# Count how many a Boolean take a 'true' value in GeoGebra

Tags: random, statistics, boolean, probability, geogebra

so.. i need to calculate the probability of finding a random point in a circle involved by a square like this screenshot in Geogebra

.[image]
so what did I do :

- i created a `poly` square  and a circle
- I was introduced this command `RandomPointIn( poly )` for create a randomly point called "F" in the square region
- make a Boolean that take 'true' when the point in the circle   ,and 'false' otherwise : `If(F ∈ circle, true, false)`
- now i created a button for Update the position  of the random point with this command on click `UpdateConstruction()`

now i need to click the button for example 100 and then i count how many the point Appear in the circle devised by the total number 100 times I expect to get approximate : 
 π/4 , that mean 78.5% .

so my problem is how to count number of clicking  and number of the Boolean take the "true" value 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found how :

create  integers `n`, `m` 
and  `s=if(a,1,0)`
just whene you create the button update write that in the script :

```
 UpdateConstruction()
 n=n+1
 m=m+s
```